# How to print out all the element text appended with a counter in separated lines using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, enumeration, enumerate

Code:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="field-options"]')
for element in elements:
    options = element.text  
    print(options)
```

This gives the output:

```
elementONE
elementTWO
elementTHREE
```

How can I count every element from the list and print the number before each element so it would look like:

```
1   elementONE
2   elementTWO
3   elementTHREE
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for that:

```
for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    options = element.text  
    print(i, options)
```

The default start index is 0 so the above will output:

```
0   elementONE
1   elementTWO
...
```

You can customise it by adding the `start` argument:

```
for i, element in enumerate(elements, start=1):
    #...
```

Comment: Do I have to define enumerate or something? Because it's just printing out a "0" at the first line.

Comment: `enumerate` is built-in Python, you shouldn't need any further definition. Is the first `element.text` an empty string perhaps?

Comment: don't think so. Seems like it's handling the elements in `elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath` as one string. I'am a beginner at python but do I need to split them or converting them into a list? Currently the output just puts a 0 before the first element.

Comment: `driver.find_elementS...` returns a list, so you're good for `elements` being a list. What do you get if you do a `print(len(elements))`?

Comment: 1 . But there are three elements on the page

Comment: That means there's nothing wrong with the `for` loop, but with the way you identify `elements`, which is really a different issue to the one in your post. I would suggest creating a new question for that, adding the relevant HTML source and code, so things don't get muddled-up.

Comment: Just had another look at the xpath and your replies. Are you sure you are using an xpath that matches the three elements and not one that matches the *parent* element? Doing a Ctrl+F in the browser's DevTools on the xpath would show you how many elements it matches.

Answer (score 1):

To append a counter starting from **1** to each list item you can use [python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  for count, item in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="field-options"]')):
      print(count+1, item.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1 elementONE
  2 elementTWO
  3 elementTHREE
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    options = element.text  
    print(i+1, options)
```

Hope this helps you!